# How can get the parent iFrame ID when blur in tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I implemented 4 TinyMCE editors on one page. I want to get the editor ID when the user leaves the TinyMCE editor and put the editor's html in the textarea. On blur I can get the editor html. but I can't find the iFrame ID in Firefox and IE. I tried this code.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "table,insertdatetime,fullscreen,searchreplace,emotions,paste,",
    selector: "#vereinbarungen",
    selector: "#narration",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "insertdate,inserttime,|,hr,emotions,|,search,replace,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,|,fullscreen", 
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : "%d.%m.%Y",
    plugin_insertdate_timeFormat : "%H:%M:%S",
    setup : function(ed) {    
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, event) {
            var dom = ed.dom,
            doc = ed.getDoc(),
            el = doc.content_editable ? ed.getBody() : (tinymce.isGecko ? doc : ed.getWin());
            tinymce.dom.Event.add(el, 'blur', function(e) {

                //this is the targeted iframe id this works in chrome but not works in other browsers.

                target_id = el.frameElement.id;
                html = $(ed.getBody()).html();
            });
        });
    },

});
```

When I tried this code with Chrome I get the `target_id` but when I try with other browsers `el.frameElement` is undefined.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check all the objects and its values of tinymce and I get the active editor ID by

`tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.editorId;`

This return the active editor ID

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question what you want to do when the editor is blurred is to update the underlying `<textarea>` with the current value of the editor.

The `triggerSave()` API in TinyMCE will do what you want automatically without having to do any of the manual JavaScript work you are currently doing.

Here are examples:

- TinyMCE 5: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8Ogaab/4
- TinyMCE 4: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8Ogaab/5

The key code is this:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('blur', function (e) {
        console.log('Triggering a Save');
        tinymce.triggerSave();
        console.log(document.getElementById('content').value);
    });
}
```

I use JavaScript to show what is in the `<textarea>` after the `triggerSave()` call completes but you would not need these `console.log()` calls other than for debugging.

Comment: I used old version of TinyMCE, When I tried `tinymce.triggerSave()` function I got an error message `Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.triggerSave is not a function`. I can't upgrade TinyMCE due to some other dependencies. Is there any solutions for old version of TinyMCE?

Comment: What is the exact version of TinyMCE you are using?  That would be useful information to include in your post as that is important in understanding what people can suggest.

Comment: I get the editor ID using `tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.editorId`